# Heap space issue when I convert from java 7 to java 8 in eclipse mars

Tags: java-8, heap-memory, eclipse-mars

I am using 4 projects together in a single workspace. Currently I am using Eclipse mars (32-bit) and JAVA 7. When I tried to change Java 7 to Java 8, I am facing Java heap size no memory issue. Is there any other configuration to be updated while upgrading from java 7 to java 8 ?

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your machine? What's your operating system name / version?

Comment: I am using 8GB RAM in my machine. OS is Windows8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your source code makes heavy use of generics, increased demands of heap space may be due to intrinsic complexity of the new type inference in Java 8.

Under `Preferences > General` you can enable `[x] Show heap status` to watch heap usage over time.

Finally, have a look at [FAQ How do I increase the heap size available to Eclipse?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F)

Comment: So, this link which we have given specifies some eclipse.ini file config settings. Will it be accepted in 32-bit eclipse?

Comment: eclipse.ini is independent of bitness. Just some vmargs may be accepted by one vm and not accepted by another vm (speaking of different vm vendors, e.g.).